# Gammu using Mysql - Access shows records as #deleted

Tags: mysql, gammu

I have been trying for a few days to resolve a problem I am having with gammu

Backend is msyql 5.7 , odbc connector 5.3 , access front end.

Gammu working fine, MySQL shows records in inbox and sentbox, but access shows both these tables as all records #deleted.

I have found out there is a problem using BIGINT as primary key - but gammu configures it with just INT unsigned , and changing this doesn't help.

Recreating the table manually , without any triggers or defaults, gives the same problem.

Removing the Primary key from the inbox makes it all work fine - records then visible on access.
But even creating a second key field will make them all come up deleted again!

I think I have tried just about every combination of removing defaults and settings I can find but am still stuck.
From playing around with it appears to be a problem relating to the ID field.

The data is fine - if I run a query on access to create a new table from inbox, the new table displays the data no problem.

Has anyone got any experience of this happening to them or any ideas?

Update...… I have discovered that playing around with access queries, the data display fine IF I omit UDH and Text fields …. adding either of those and all records are #deleted. They are of TEXT type, but then so is the textdecoded field and that one works OK.

I reckon I can work around this, but would still be interested to know what is going on - looks like Access doesn't like the content of these fields one little bit.

Many thanks....

Comment: It's probably your odbc connector. What version have you installed? And what version of mysql server? Exact version

Comment: Server is 5.7.25, and connector is 5.3 ANSI …..  thanks for commenting...

Comment: Changed to 5.2 MySQL connector and problem completely resolved. Thank you for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: You can use 5.3.9 that is stable that I know of @David

Comment: Thank you I will